# Providing a fallback image url based on a boolean value in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, spotify

I'm currently using Spotify's API to gather artist images and things work just as expected.

```
require 'rspotify'

class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessor: :image

    before_save :get_image

    def get_image
        artist = RSpotify::Artist.search(self.name).first
        if artist.nil?
            self.image = 'avatar@2x.png'
        else    
            self.image = artist.images.first
            self.image = image['url']
        end
    end
end
```

What concerns me is there are often times where an artist shares the same name as one that is lesser know causing a bit of a mixup. So for instance if I have an artist on my site named "John Doe" and Spotify also has an artist with that same name but is a completely different person the the wrong person's image is shown.

To fix this issue I was thinking of adding a checkbox in my edit form that asks, "Correct artist image?". If false then a default avatar is used from my public directory. The only problem with what I have now is that the `before_save` callback I have in my artist model uses Spotify's images no matter what. Is there a way where I could set something up in my form's edit view that would in a sense override this callback and use this fallback url based on the value of my checkbox?

```
<%= simple_form_for @artist do |f| %>

    <div class="input">
        <%= f.input :name %>
    </div>

    <%= image_tag @artist.image %>

    <%= label_tag 'Correct Artist Image?' %>
    <%= check_box_tag 'Correct Artist Image?' %>

  <%= f.submit %>
<% end>
```

**Show View**

```
<% if correct_image %>
   <%= image_tag @artist.image %>
<% else %>
  <%= image_tag 'avatar@2x.png' %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still use the `before_save` callback you already have. With a bit of refactoring you can just have a condition that only sets the Spotify image if the image is flagged as correct. This can be done by adding a non-persistent property to `Artist` that the form would use:

controllers/artists_controller.rb

```
class ArtistsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @artist = Artist.new(artist_params)
    #...
    @artist.save
  end

  private
  def artist_params
    params.require(:artist).permit(:is_correct_image) #... etc
  end

end
```

models/artist.rb

```
class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessable :is_correct_image

  before_save :assign_image
  def assign_image
    if @is_correct_image == '0'
      set_spotify_image
    else
      set_default_image
    end
  end

  private 
  def set_default_image
    self.image = 'avatar@2x.png'
  end

  def set_spotify_image
    artist = RSpotify::Artist.search(self.name).first
    if artist.nil?
      set_default_image
    else
      image = artist.images.first
      self.image = image['url']
    end
  end
end
```

view.html.erb

```
...
<%= f.check_box :is_correct_image %>
```

Comment: My only question at first glance lies within the first line in the `assign_image` method. Is `@is_correct_image` supposed to be an instance variable? I see that its referencing the value of the checkbox but I'm just trying to understand how its doing it. The one reason its tripping me up is because I'm so used to instance variables representing instances of models vs. attributes.

Comment: Yep, it's meant to be an instance variable rather than an ActiveRecord attribute because the value is not actually saved to the database. The `attr_accessor` allows `@is_correct_image` to the set within `Artist.new()` (along with the AR attributes) which is how it's possible for the `params` hash to set `@is_correct_image`.

Comment: Is there a way so that the checkbox stays checked/unchecked once the edit form is submitted? That seems to be the only thing that's not working

Comment: In that case you would need to save that state in the DB, perhaps with a extra column/attribute of `custom_image` (Boolean).